# limiting imregister/imregtform to whole-pixel translations (i.e. no subpixels)

Tags: matlab

I am registering multi-modal MRI slices that are 512x512 greyscale (each normalised to 0..1 range). The slices are of the same object but taken with different sequences and have very different intensities. I am currently finding the translation-only transformation between the two slices using `imregister(moving,fixed,'translation',optimizer,metric)` where `optimizer` and `metric` are from `imregconfig('multimodal')`.

However, the transformation it finds (inspecting `tform`) is like '2.283' in the x and '-0.019' in the y, and actually I only wish for whole value translations i.e. '2' and '0' in this case.

1. How to modify `imregister` (or a similar function) to check only whole-pixel translations? This would save a lot of computation and it suits my needs better.
2. Without modifying `imregister` I assume the easiest solution to just `round` the x and y translations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how `imregister` is implemented for the `'multimodal'` case, but pure translation estimation for conventional image registration is done using image gradients and taylor apporximation and gives sub-pixel accuracy at the same cost as pixel-level accuracy.
So, in that case limiting yourself to pixel-wise translation does not seems to benefit you in any way.

If you do not want to bother with sib-pixel shifts, I suppose `round`ing would be the simplest approach.

Comment: How can create a new similarity metric for `imregister`? similar to `MeanSquares` or `MattesMutualInformation`.

Comment: @Mohammadnagdawi better ask a new question for this

Comment: I can't ask more questions. SO think my questions does not good so If this question doesn't get ans my account subject to block